# Regex help: how can I match all characters but leave one white space in between strings?

Tags: regex

I want to be able to match each row as one group capturing all characters while leaving one space separating the words/strings.

This is what I have so far, I can't seem to get past the 2nd column -

https://regex101.com/r/IXMVci/3

Comment: Please include examples of the text you want to match and the expression you tried directly in your question.

Comment: Wait, either you want to _capture_ or you want to _replace_. You can't capture anything which is not there. If there are 5 white spaces between two values, they must be included in the capture, or you need to capture the parts individually (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *capture* a whole string, exclude some characters in between, and continue the match with the following characters in the same group. What you *can* do, is match the parts individually:

```
([0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ -_][A-Za-z]+)+|[A-Za-z0-9]+|-)
```

This should select every column in your sample data. By using a sub-group I made sure a white space will not be matched in the end of a column.

However, after some columns are separated by only 1 white space, I limited a part of the column after a potential whitespace to only characters (no numbers).

To separate the first column (which only is followed by 1 regex), I added the first alternative

Comment: Ah okay, I figured you could be as specific as you wanted with regex. Wow, cool, that's almost perfect but it's separating the first character in the second column from the others..

Comment: Test the regex in your fiddle and check the matches: no separation of the first character in the 2nd column. I guess, your implementation handles alternatives slightly differently. But, because you didn't post any information about what language you are using, I optimized for the fiddle you provided